# Kotlin: Code processing without user input

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

```
package test

    fun main() {

        val x= readLine()!!.toInt()
        for (i in 1..x) {
            repeat(x) { print("#") }
            println()
        }
    }
```

This is my edited code after your suggestions, stiill, the output remains the same despite my input. It says the source code finished with exit code 0

Comment: How do you run the code? Try without `private object TestStringGen` and just put `fun main() { ... }` at the top-level

Comment: Thank you, however, when I input anything, the output remains the same as the process finished with exit code 0, my code has been edited now to show what I have done

Answer (score 0):

You answer is already here in the comment of Nikolai Shevchenko, you don't need that `TestStringGen` object wrapped around the main class, you can't even actually run it at all with it there.

I'm just adding this here as an addition, you don't need the second loop. Since the digit itself represents the number of `#` you need, you could just take advantage of [repeat](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html):

```
val myNumber = readLine()!!.toInt()

for (digit in 1..myNumber) {
    repeat(digit) { print("#") }
    println()
}
```

Also, no need to start the range of the loop from `1` because that will always be an empty line. Unless you need the spacing for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you, however, when I input anything, the output remains the same as the process finished with exit code 0, my code has been edited now to show what I have done